# How to efficiently generate List<DateTime> based on custom patterns?

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm building a webapp that can display dates on a calendar based on 'Pattern' user can select. This the pattern selection controls from web UI

[image]

Now once he select a pattern he can click on 'Generate Dates' button and an API call will be made to server to calculate the dates based on pattern selection.

- I was able to generate dates when user selects PatternMode='DAY' and 'WEEK' with the below code.
- I was not able to handle when he selects 'MONTH' or 'YEAR' as PetternMode
- When he selects 'Month' as PatternMode and 'DayOfMonth' as Constrain => I was able to generate dates unless PatternValue=1. When he changes Pattern value to 2 or something it breaks.
- How to handle patterns like 'Every 2 months', 'Every second saturdays' etc..
- Is there any library or way to increase efficiency of this code? (Least priority)

This is what I tried :

```cs
public static List<DateTime> GenerateUpcomingDates(this Repeat repeat, 
     DateTime from, DateTime till) 
{
    List<DateTime> result = new List<DateTime>();

    //DAY MODE
    if (repeat.PatternMode == PATTERNMODE.Day) 
    {
        while (from <= till) 
        {
            result.Add(from);
            from = from.AddDays(repeat.PatternValue);
        }
        return result;
    }

    //WEEK MODE
    else if (repeat.PatternMode == PATTERNMODE.Week) 
    {
        while (from <= till) 
        {
            if (repeat.Sunday && from.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday) 
            {
                result.Add(from);
            }
            
            if (repeat.Monday && from.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday) 
            {
                result.Add(from);
            }
              
            if (repeat.Tuesday && from.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday) 
            {
                result.Add(from);
            }
              
            if (repeat.Wednesday && from.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday) 
            {
                result.Add(from);
            }
            
            if (repeat.Thursday && from.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday) 
            {
                result.Add(from);
            }
            
            if (repeat.Friday && from.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday) 
            {
                result.Add(from);
            }
              
            if (repeat.Saturday && from.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday) 
            {
                result.Add(from);
            }
            
            from = from.AddDays(repeat.PatternValue);
        }
            
        return result;
    }

    //MONTH MODE
    if (repeat.PatternMode == PATTERNMODE.Month) 
    {
        if (repeat.Constrain == CONSTRAIN.DayOfMonth) 
        {
            //This works only when patternValue=1
            while (from <= till) 
            {
                if (from == new DateTime(from.Year, from.Month, repeat.DayOfMonth)) 
                {
                  result.Add(from);
                }
                
                from = from.AddDays(1);
            }
              return result;
        } 
        else if (repeat.Constrain == CONSTRAIN.Logical) 
        {
              //Not working...
        }
        
    }
   
    //YEAR MODE
    // Not implemented...
    
    
    return new List < DateTime > ();
}
```

---

This is how I call the above extension method (to generate a list of dates for the next 1 year starting from one date) :

```cs
var UpcomingDates = repeat.GenerateUpcomingDates(repeat.StartBy, repeat.StartBy.AddYears(1))
```

This is the result so far I can achieve

[image]

These are the ENUM's and Repeat class :

```
public class Repeat 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }
    
    public COURSE Course { get; set; }
    
    public int PatternValue { get; set; }
      
    public PATTERNMODE PatternMode { get; set; }
    
    public bool Sunday { get; set; }
    
    public bool Monday { get; set; }
    
    public bool Tuesday { get; set; }
    
    public bool Wednesday { get; set; }
    
    public bool Thursday { get; set; }
    
    public bool Friday { get; set; }
    
    public bool Saturday { get; set; }
    
    public CONSTRAIN Constrain { get; set; }
    
    public int DayOfMonth { get; set; }
    
    public LOGICALSTART LogicalStart { get; set; }
    
    public DAY LogicalDay { get; set; }
    
    public DateTime StartBy { get; set; }
    
    public TIMEMODE TimeMode { get; set; }
    
    public DateTime SpecificTime { get; set; }
    
    public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }
}

public enum COURSE 
{
    OneTime = 1,
    SeveralTimes = 2
}

public enum PATTERNMODE 
{
    Day = 1,
    Week = 2,
    Month = 3,
    Year = 4
}
    
public enum CONSTRAIN 
{
    DayOfMonth = 1,
    Logical = 2,
}

public enum LOGICALSTART 
{
    First = 1,
    Second = 2,
    Third = 3,
    Fourth = 4,
    Last = 0
}

public enum DAY 
{
    Sunday = 1,
    Monday = 2,
    Tuesday = 3,
    Wednesday = 4,
    Thursday = 5,
    Friday = 6,
    Saturday = 7,
}

public enum TIMEMODE 
{
    Adaptive = 1,
    Specific = 2
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code for `Repeat`, `PATTERNMODE`, `TIMEMODE`, and `CONSTRAIN`.

Comment: PATTERNMODE and CONSTRAIN are enums, I added those in screenshot above in brackets

Comment: Please provide the code as code.

Comment: The time it takes to write "PATTERNMODE and CONSTRAIN are enums, I added those in screenshot above in brackets" is probably longer than the time it would take to copy and paste your code.

Comment: Fine. Modified question and included

Comment: Thank you. It's much appreciated when we can run your code.

Comment: Why not to go with a cron expression? Frontend will generate cron string based on a user input and pass it to the backend. Generate dates from the  cron string is a trivial thing to do, there are plenty of libraries for that.

Comment: Thanks mate for suggestion. I thought about it before but I found few issues. First of all I can't present a CRON expression selector to the user. He had to select his pattern form this UI. In that case then I had to convert this Repeat expression to a CRON expression using an adapter function which I'm not sure how to do.

Comment: Out of interest, if I choose the running day of 29th of each month, what do you expect to happen on non-leap years? It to occur once on 1st march and again on 29th March? Skip February? (Leap years are always hard when dealing with dates!)

Comment: Also what does "Run every 1 day, on the second saturday" actually mean? Same with "Run every 1 week on the 9th day". There seems to be plenty of edge cases with your requirements - and all this was solved eons ago with cron syntax for scheduling jobs which really gives you everything you need. See https://crontab.guru/ for a good UI

Comment: I do understand. So in that case if I can use CRON expression what's the way to convert user selection to a cron expression with some function. The issue is I can't ask the user to enter a CRON expression. The user is not technical

Comment: Id first iron out the weird edge cases in your setup UI as discussed above. You probably want to avoid the hour/minute part of cron syntax if thats not interesting to you but the 3rd, 4th & 5th positions in cron are easy enough to use. Ask the user what day (or days) of the month, how often (daily,monthly weekly etc) and which week (or weeks). I suggest you have a good look at the link I put above

Comment: http://www.raboof.com/projects/ncrontab/ also looks really useful to convert the cron syntax to the occurences you want in .net